# if statement without a condition

Tags: python

```
def f1(x,y):
      if x:    
          x = [1,2,3]
          x.append(4)
      else:
          x = 2
      return x + y

L1 = [1,2,3]
L2 = [55,66]
L3 = []
y = 3
print( f1(L3,y) )            # Line 1
print( L3 )                  # Line 2
print( f1(L1,L2) )           # Line 3
print( L1 )                  # Line 4
```

#I want to understand this expression, what is it saying? what does "if  x:" means? usualy there is always a condition after the if statement, but this one doesn have one. how do I make sense of this? and what is it doing in this fuction?

Comment: That may be an `if` statement without a *comparison* but it definitely *does* have a condition. An if statement without a condition would look something like this: `if :` :-)

Comment: you're right. I just used the wrong words, but I think you understood my question. can you give me an answer, please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is to check whether x is true or false(binary).

`if x:`

returns true when the x value is not equal to 0(when x is a number) and it returns true if it has at least a character(when x is a string). It returns false if x is equal to '0' or '' or 'None'

For Eg:

```
a = 10
if a:
    print a
```

This prints '10'

```
a = 'DaiMaria'
if a:
    print a
```

This prints 'DaiMaria'

```
a = 0.1
if a:
    print a
```

Prints 0.1

```
a = 0
if a:
    print a
```

Prints nothing as it returned False.

```
a = None
if a:
    print a
```

Prints nothing as it returns False.

```
a = ''
if a:
    print a
```

Prints nothing as it returns False.

Answer (score 5):

The condition is whether or not x is a [truthy value](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is equivalent to `if bool(x): ...` where Python first tries to look for a `__nonzero__` method on `x` (`__bool__` in Python 3) and if it cannot find it returns `True` per default *unless* `x` is `None`, `False`, has a `__len__` method that returns zero, is an empty mapping or a numeric type with value zero.

Some examples:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> bool(A())
True
>>> class B(object):
...     def __nonzero__(self): return False
... 
>>> bool(B())
False
>>> class C(object):
...     def __len__(self): return 0
... 
>>> bool(C())
False
>>> class D(object):
...     def __len__(self): return 0
...     def __nonzero__(self): return True
... 
>>> bool(D())
True
```