# Understanding this Python ‘if statement’ with unfamiliar expression type

Tags: python, if-statement, expression

Apologies if this is a straightforward thing, I’m just not having luck getting answers online (and if this isn’t a good place to post).

I’ve been trying to improve my Python, and I’ve been trying to make sense of some code for a Neural Network/Natural Language Processing package. I came across this:

```
if args.encoder_layers_to_keep:
        args.encoder_layers = len(args.encoder_layers_to_keep.split(","))
```

I haven’t come across an if statement with an expression like this. There’s no comparison between variables or anything. My only guess is that it returns a true or false value and works with that but I’m really not sure.

For reference, here’s the full script - https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/master/fairseq/models/transformer.py

I’d appreciate any help with this.

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: If `args.encoder_layers_to_keep` has a boolean equivalent of `true` it will evaluate to true or if it has an integer value other than `0`, it will again evaluate to true. Otherwise, it will be false. Or empty string -> false while any other string -> true, as stated in the below answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if statement without a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43063267/if-statement-without-a-condition)

Comment: `args` is an object passed as an argument to a method. `encoder_layers_to_keep` is a property of args. Judging by the following line, it is expected to be a string. An empty string, `None` and `False` are examples of [falsy values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/567595) in python. The nested statement will only be executed if the property is a truthy value such as a non-empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empty sequences (e.g., lists, tuples, strings) evaluate to `False`. Non-empty sequences evaluate to `True`.

`args.encoder_layers_to_keep` seems to be a string variable. An empty string `""` evaluates to `False`, and a non-empty string evaluates to `True`.

You can prove this to yourself by using the builtin function `bool` to convert to a boolean. Try `bool("")` and `bool("foobar")`.

This is suggested in the [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) (PEP8):

> For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false:
>
> ```
> if not seq:
> if seq:
>
> # Wrong:
> if len(seq):
> if not len(seq):
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I’ve been seeing these everywhere yet never in any tutorials or explanations online. So, does it have any other special uses over like `if variable = 0:` or is it just ‘proper notation’ per se?

Comment: Nope, no special uses over `if variable == 0`. It's a bit of a shortcut, I guess, because you don't have to use `len` (the `len` of an empty sequence is 0). If this was the answer to your question, please select the green arrow to mark it as the answer.